# GitHub Get an email when someone follows me

Tags: git, email, github, notifications

Maybe I'm missing something super obvious, but I went into my notification settings and can't find anything about getting emails when people follow you. I can always go to my Followers tab on my profile to see who is currently following me, but I'd like to get updates.

The only way I found out new people followed me was accidentally going to plain old [GitHub.com](https://github.com/) and glancing at my activity.

Answer (score 3):

You would normally [create](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/) a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) for that.

But for the [Follow Event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#followevent), it is documented:

> Events of this type are no longer delivered, but it's possible that they exist in timelines of some users. You cannot create webhooks that listen to these events.

The alternative would be to setup a poll service, a cron job that would poll regularly a GitHub User to get the [number of followers](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/), and send an email if that number changes.

---

In 2021, you would use a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions), like [Soros Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5143776/sorosliu) did with [`Sorosliu1029/follower-change`](https://github.com/Sorosliu1029/follower-change)

```yaml
name: "GitHub follower change event"
description: "To get follow and unfollow event, could run as a cron job"
author: "Soros Liu"
branding:
  icon: "user-check"
  color: "green"
inputs:
  myToken:
    description: "github personal access token"
    required: true
  notifyUnFollowEvent:
    description: "should notify unfollow event or not"
    required: false
    default: "false"
outputs:
  changed:
    description: "whether follower changed or not"
  shouldNotify:
    description: "skip notification when no change or first run"
  markdown:
    description: "markdown for follower change info"
  plainText:
    description: "plain text for follower change info"
  htmlFilePath:
    description: "path of html file for follower change info"
runs:
  using: "node12"
  main: "dist/index.js"
```

> ### How it works ?
>
> It is not realtime, since GitHub does not provide 'follow' events.
>
> So you may run it periodically as a `cron` job.
>
> - Use GitHub GraphQL API to get all current followers
> - Download previous snapshotted followers from GitHub Action artifact
> - Compare current followers with previous followers to get follow and unfollow events
> - Upload current followers as new snapshot to GitHub Action artifact

Result:

[image: new followers]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this service:
https://github-follow.herokuapp.com/

Quote:

> If you're a Developer, you're most probably familiar with GitHub & its
> notification system. Currently, GitHub provides email notifications to
> watched repositories & mentions. However, GitHub fails to provide a
> similar email notification when someone follows / unfollows you.
>
> This GitHub App solves this issue by mailing the users on a daily
> basis if they have any new followers / unfollowers - to the email ID
> which is associated with their GitHub account. To use this App, just
> click the button below & authorize this App to access your public
> information. As simple as that.

Comment: this app is no longer available now

Answer (score 0):

you can use this service and you will receive a notification when some one follow or unfollow you

https://github-followers-tracker.haythemdridi.com

[image]